# Marry() - это и объект и функция? .husband и .wife какую функцию выполняет?

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

```js
function marry(man, woman) {
  woman.husband = man;
  man.wife = woman;

  return {
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  }
}

let family = marry({
  name: "John"
}, {
  name: "Ann"
});
```

Comment: функция просто возвращает новый объект, что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: Функция тривиальная. Добавьте в конце `console.log(famiy)` да посмотрите.

Comment: @ThisMan ну не просто а с сайд эффектом =)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ ну да, у объектов появятся ссылки друг на друга еще, просто не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: а еще тут есть проблемы с `code of conduct` :D

Comment: @ThisMan Почему в коде используется husband и wife? Они свойства или что-то другое? woman.husband==father Они равны ?

Comment: а вы пробовали перевести названия переменных? с английского на русский, тогда сразу будет понятно, что значат переменные и сама функция

Comment: _woman.husband==father_ да

Comment: @ThisMan Я знаю английский(+ 4 языка) :) Я просто код не понимаю и путаюсь.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, `parent1` и `parent2` предлагаете?

Comment: @TotalPusher я - нет, не предлагаю, однако почему-то(наверное под влиянием драмы на мете) мне бросилось это в глаза

Comment: _Я просто код не понимаю_ а вы этот код где нашли? Должна же быть первоначальная задача или это код без контекста?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q Ну что сделать, не все же гении как вы. Я новичок. Не знать - не стыдно, стыдно не учиться(не спросить). Придем к code of conduct, да возможно есть проблемы, модераторы не исправили. Надеюсь мои вопросы больше не будут бросаться в глаза.

Comment: @Afina а к Вам претензий нет, это Ваше право считать как Ваам угодно :)

Comment: @ThisMan https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection#vzaimosvyazannye-obekty <-- отсюда я взяла код

Comment: там же ниже есть объяснение кода) _функция связывает объекты, добавляя обоим ссылку друг на друг_

Comment: @ThisMan Я конечно прочла объяснение. Код странный и результат кода вообще странный. По отдельности функция, объект, свойства, значения понятны, а вместе все они создают смешанную топологию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте просто объясню каждую строчку кода, что бы было понятно, что он делает. 
*Хотя все равно еще не ясно, что именно не понятно*

```js
// Функция принимает два объекта.
function marry(man, woman) {
  // Здесь мы связываем эти объекты:
  // То есть теперь woman имеет ссылку на man через св-во husband
  // А man имеет ссылку на woman через св-во wife
  // Так как это объекты, то изменения сохранятся после выполнения функции
  woman.husband = man;
  man.wife = woman;

  // Возвращаем новый объект со св-вами, где хранятся объекты
  // которые мы передали в функцию
  return {
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  }
}


const john = {
  name: 'John',
}
const ann = {
  name: 'Ann',
}
const family = marry(john, ann);

// Теперь у ann и john есть ссылки друг на друга
console.log('is john father', family.father === john);
console.log('is ann mother', family.mother === ann);
console.log('is john ann`s husband', ann.husband === john);
console.log('is ann john`s wife', john.wife === ann);
```

**P.S** 
Есть такая структура данных **двусвязный список**, это список, где каждый элемент имеет ссылку на предыдущий и следующий за ним элемент. Примерно это выглядит вот так:

```
[prev: null, id: 0, next: 1] > // Первый элемент, поэтому prev === null
[prev: 0, id: 1, next: 2] > ...
[prev: N - 2, id: N - 1, next: null] // последний элемент N-списка, поэтому next === null
```

Так вот для создания узлов, может использоваться подобная техника

```js
function createNode(id, prevNode = null) {
  // Связываем узлы
  const newNode = {prev: prevNode, id, next: null}; // новому подставили предыдущий узел
  if(prevNode) {
     // Предыдущему поставили новый, как следующий
    prevNode.next = newNode;
  }
  return newNode;
}

const root = createNode(0);
const node2 = createNode(1, root);
const node3 = createNode(2, node2); // и так далее
// В итоге через root можно будет добраться до любого узла
console.log(root);
```

**P.P.S** 
*вывод через консоль во строенном редакторе на этом сайте выглядит так из-за бесконечных цикличных ссылок, если вставить просто в консоль, результат будет без всяких ref, id*

Comment: 1) Откуда взялись **husband** и **wife**.  2) Почему так не записали их let woman = {
husband : "man"
};
let man = {
wife: "woman"
};  3)  В предложении _И возвращает новый объект, содержащий ссылки на два предыдущих._   под словосочетанием **новый объект** что имели ввиду? return {
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  } Или там должен быть словосочетание **новые объекты** (то есть father and mother, хотя они являются свойствами) . Или же return ***nameOfObject*** ={
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  } То есть как называется этот объект? P.S. Я пока ваш ответ не анализировала

Comment: что значит вы не анализировали мой ответ, но задаете вопросы?) `wife`, `husband` это просто названия полей, называйте как хотите, новый объект, значит новый объект `{}`, _let woman = { husband : "man" }_ тут `man` это строка, а не объект

Comment: лучше сначала прочитайте вдумчиво мой ответ, а потом задайте вопросы)

Comment: Я потом анализировала, но я не нашла ответ на эти вопросы. Если бы я нашла ответы то я удалила бы коммент. А ваш ответ мне очень понравился в целом, там вы затронули интересную тему ) Спасибо большое ) **woman.husband=man;** Я знаю что здесь **man** - это объект, **woman** - это тоже объект, а **husband** -это свойства объекта.  Сначала так не надо было написать **let woman={husband: "man"}** ? А потом это **woman.husband=man;** ? То есть свойства **husband**  надо же была сначала объявить как в **let woman={....}** ?

Comment: _То есть свойства husband надо же была сначала объявить_ зачем? да еще и ненужной строкой, хотя по факту там будет храниться объект. Св-ва в `js` можно добавлять динамически, уже после создания объекта. Тут суть в том, что бы добавить св-во именно объекту, который передали в функцию, а вы предлагаете другое

Comment: Понятно, вот я не знала что _свойства в JavaScript можно добавлять динамически_ , потому что ни в одной статье не было написано. И еще один вопрос у меня; здесь ***// Возвращаем _новый объект_ со св-вами, где хранятся объекты
  // которые мы передали в функцию
  return {
    father: man,
    mother: woman
  }
}** новый объект безымянный(анонимный)? Например **return user ={ name: "Melinda", surname:"Gates" }**, в этом примере у объекта есть имя **user**. А вышеприведенном примере просто return с фигурными скобками.

Comment: @Afina у объекта нет имени, это у переменной есть имя ( идентификатор ), но да, необязательно создавать переменную для объекта, можно сразу возвращать объект ( любое значение )